# Accord.net haar object detection

Tags: c#

I'm trying to build robot arm which is capable of recognize trained objects. I know it can be done with opencv. But I'm not fluent in C++ programming. So I need to do it with C#. First I use Aforge.net and I recognize objects using color filtering, but it is poor method. So I found Accord.net has advanced techniques to do that. Haar feature object detection is one of that. I read the Accord.net documentation. It has a constructor

```
HaarCascade(Int32, Int32,HaarCascadeStage[])
```

first two integers are base width & base height. What are them. What is stages? How to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look on [Accord.NET documentation](http://accord.googlecode.com/svn/docs/html/T_Accord_Vision_Detection_HaarCascade.htm). There is also the [accompanying CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441226/Haar-feature-Object-Detection-in-Csharp) article which explains what a stage is and even demonstrates how to create a Haar Object Detector using a Haar Cascade.

Also, please keep in mind that the current implementation can only use existent classifiers to perform the recognition. The framework does not yet offer a way to create your own classifiers at this time. However, note that it can work with any OpenCV-compatible XML definition of a Haar cascade, such as any of the ones which come bundled in OpenCV or even definitions created by [other researchers](http://alereimondo.no-ip.org/OpenCV/34).